# Nginx возвращает файлы

Tags: nginx

Nginx вместо "компиляции" php, тупо отдаёт его как файл. Подскажите плиз, что не так в конфиге

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name xxx.com;
    root /home/xxx/public/;

    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log info;


    location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404 ;

    }

    location ~ \.php\$ {
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf;
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
     }

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/xxx.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/xxx.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot


}
server {
    if ($host = xxx.com) {
       return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen 80;
    server_name xxx.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Должно быть не

```
location ~ \.php\$ {
```

а

```
location ~ \.php$ {
```